# Reporting Services Visible Toggle

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

IN SQL Server Reporting Services 2008r2 I have a report with 3 child sub reports that drill in to reveal more data detail. The sub reports are hidden on initial render and revealed by clicking a toggle set on a data item. I would like to hide the toggle option where the row doesn't have any child rows to drill into (saving people from clicks.) I can't see an option for that - and when i tried setting the visibility toggle to an expression it didn't like it; is there another mechanism to control the visibility of the toggle?